# Android What is "int groupPosition" in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

While setting listener I have the method where I need to fetch View of groupItem. How can I  do it throughtout method onGroupExpand:

```
    list.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) { 

        } 
    }); `
```

I need View of groupItem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Adapter, you can add the following method:

```
public View getGroupView(int grpPosition, ...) {
  return myGroupCollection.get(grpPosition);
}
```

When calling the onGroupExpand method, you can ask the views from your Adapter:

```
list.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) { 
         View v = myAdapter.getGroupView(groupPosition).findBy....
         // Do other stuff you like
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by myGroupCollection?

Comment: Depends on your implementation.. In your Adapter you will have for example an Array of Groups and an Array of Childs. The myGroupCollection will refer to the Array of Groups.

Comment: Yes, but my array of Groups consists of Map<String,String>. So how can I fetch  View from it?